# To recognize the numbers and special characters in a string Java

Tags: java, string, numbers, character, special-characters

I have a question:

I have two strings in Java Code:

```
1) hello
2) 01234
```

I want to implement a code that knows how to recognize that the string "01234" consists of only numbers or special characters (such as . , * , ? or others) and that the string "hello" consists of only string characters.

How Can I implement it?

Comment: One option use regex and check `[0-9*.,]+` matches numbers and some symbols. `[a-zA-Z]+` matches only letters.

Comment: Iterate through string and check each character

Comment: What is wrong with iterating over all characters in string and increasing counter of letters, numbers, special characters according to character you are testing?

Comment: Would you like to write one function that returns a result for both of your examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach is to use a regular expression, for example "\d+" would check for only digits.

```
String regex = "\\d+";
System.out.println("123".matches(regex)); // <-- true, 123 is all digits.
```

However, that doesn't address your *special characters*. So, a cleaner solution might be to use [`Character.isLetter(char)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter%28char%29) and something like,

```
public static boolean isLetters(String in) {
    if (in != null) {
        for (char ch : in.toCharArray()) {
            if (!Character.isLetter(ch)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then your `isDigits()` test could look something like,

```
public static boolean isDigitsOrSpecial(String in) {
    if (in != null) {
        for (char ch : in.toCharArray()) {
            if (Character.isLetter(ch)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I have tried the regex solution and it's ok. The cleaner solution is wrong: when I call this function with boolean p = isDigitsOrSpecial("12..u3") I get "true" when I want false in this case because I have "u" character. I want that this function returns true value if the string is composed ONLY by numbers or special characters